# Encountered internal error running command: Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 70

Tags: xcode, eclipse, appium-ios

I am facing this issue while i run ios script in eclipse.
In appium log displayed above mentioned issue.
is this something certificate issue ? but I have already installed the apple certificate into my xcode.

Please help me, I did not found much on web also regarding this error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you executing on simulator or real device, i have faced same issue
please provide appium server log?.

for now you can try below options

1- build webdriverAgent xcode project in xcode before executing appium script and make sure you are able to launch thier demo application from xcode.
2- update appium server.

thats what i can suggest without seeing server log.